# div after a div with top value

Tags: html, css

descBox class have top value of main Box and thats OK . here i want to div with formBox Class place exactly bottom of the div with class descBox but my problem is it seems the descBox class doesn't occupy its own container and my formBox class go inside to it not the bottom of it.what is the best way to resolve?

```css
.descBox {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div class="descBox">
    <div class="description">
      <h3>this is description</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formBox">
    <form>
      <input type="tel" class="formTextBox" placeholder="insert phone">
      <input type="button" class="formBtn">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm getting your question correctly..

You want both `divs` to be displayed `descBox` on top of `formBox`.

You can do that by adding a container and place the container with `position: absolute`.

Like so:

```css
.absContainer {
      width: 95%;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      text-align: center; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="mainBox">
      <div id="absContainer">
        <div class="descBox">
            <div class="description">
                <h3>this is description</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <form>
                <input type="tel" class="formTextBox" placeholder="insert phone"/>
                <input type="button" class="formBtn"/>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.descBox {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20% auto 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css, like this:

```css
.mainBox{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.descBox {
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div class="descBox">
    <div class="description">
      <h3>this is description</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formBox">
    <form>
      <input type="tel" class="formTextBox" placeholder="insert phone">
      <input type="button" class="formBtn">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```